# Web3 Python Value Error Transaction Type not supported

Tags: python, sendrawtransaction, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to send a signed transaction from an interaction with a smart contract but it all falls apart when sending the raw transaction.

My code is as follows

```
    import Globalvariables as thg
    bsc='https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
    w3=Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

    abi=json.loads(abi_string)

    contract_object=w3.eth.contract(address=w3.toChecksumAddress(thg.direction_market),abi=abi)

    nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount(w3.toChecksumAddress(thg.my_direction))

    #tx={'nonce':nonce,'from':w3.toChecksumAddress(thg.my_direction),'gasPrice':50000000000,'gas':277777}
    tx={'nonce':nonce,'from':w3.toChecksumAddress(thg.my_direction),'maxFeePerGas':277777,'maxPriorityFeePerGas':30000}

    input_data={'addresses':[w3.toChecksumAddress(token['owner']),w3.toChecksumAddress(token['nftContract']),w3.toChecksumAddress(thg.contract_wbnb)],
                'values':[int(token['tokenId']),int(w3.toWei(token['bnb'],'ether')),int(token['saltNonce'])],
                'signature':bytes.fromhex(token['sign'].lstrip('0x'))
                }                               
    purchase=contract_object.functions.matchTransaction(input_data['addresses'],input_data['values'],input_data['signature']).buildTransaction(tx)

    sign_tx=w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(purchase,thg.metamask)
    print(sign_tx,type(sign_tx))
    print(sign_tx.rawTransaction,type(sign_tx.rawTransaction))

    try:raw_final=w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_tx.rawTransaction)
    except:raw_final=w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_tx)
```

The codes gives back an error in both of the last 2 lines

```
>>ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'transaction type not supported'}
```

Why am I receiving this?

[In the docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=send_raw_transaction#sign-a-contract-transaction) I think I followed the code without any mistake. But, looking closer whereas in the docs when you call sign_tx.rawTransaction it returns something like this

```
>>> signed_txn.rawTransaction
HexBytes('0x02f8b00180843b9aca0084773594008301117094fb6916095ca1df60bb79ce92ce3ea74c37c5d35980b844a9059cbb000000000000000000000000fb6916095ca1df60bb79ce92ce3ea74c37c5d3590000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c001a0cec4150e52898cf1295cc4020ac0316cbf186071e7cdc5ec44eeb7cdda05afa2a06b0b3a09c7fb0112123c0bef1fd6334853a9dcf3cb5bab3ccd1f5baae926d449')
```

What I see from my code is this

```
print(signed_txn.rawTransaction,type(signed_txn.rawTransaction))
b'\x02\xf9\x01\xce8"\x82u0\x83.....', <class 'hexbytes.main.HexBytes'>
```

Why is my code returning something different?

By the way, in the previous step when signing the transaction I've noticed that in the example they use the private key like this

```
private_key = b"\xb2\\}\xb3\x1f\xee\xd9\x12''\xbf\t9\xdcv\x9a\x96VK-\xe4\xc4rm\x03[6\xec\xf
```

Whereas mine is passed as a string. Do I need to do `bytes.fromhex(thg.metamask)` instead?
Is this the root of the mistake or is it something different all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is not related to hex/binary conversions as this is mostly handled by web3.

You can easily view the hex version in python by using `.hex()`

```
h = '935479cfcb8d9b53861f4c6c5e8941ed2787710b289100235dcb6ca1182a2f24'
b = b"\x93Ty\xcf\xcb\x8d\x9bS\x86\x1fLl^\x89A\xed'\x87q\x0b(\x91\x00#]\xcbl\xa1\x18*/$"
print(b.hex())
>>> 935479cfcb8d9b53861f4c6c5e8941ed2787710b289100235dcb6ca1182a2f24
print(b.hex() == h)
>>> True
```

The actual error comes from poor formatting somewhere in your code.

Possibly from `,'maxFeePerGas':277777,'maxPriorityFeePerGas':30000` as these are mainly for Ethereum and can fail if I include them on other chains.

You should include `gas` and `gasPrice`

If you still have issue, change `gas` to `gasLimit`

You also appear to be missing the `chainId` from the transaction which will default to `ETH`

make sure to add that as well..

```
chain_id_binance = 56 # 0x38 in hex

tx = {
chainId: w3.utils.toHex(chain_id_binance),
...
}
```